# Why JavaScript objects doesn't gets copy of data and methods in ES6

Tags: javascript, class, design-patterns, ecmascript-6, es6-class

One common aspect of object-oriented design (in most of the languages, especially Java) is that when we construct new object using constructor, all the methods and public/protected instance variables gets copied into the object. For example:

```
Car myCar = new Car('Corolla', '2015');
```

Now if `Car` class has `goForward()` or `goBackward()` methods, all of them will get copied to `myCar` object.

But this is not the case in JavaScript as long as I've studied. If this has been similar in JavaScript, `myCar`had prototype that actually points to the `Car` prototype.

According to my understanding, this copying of data and methods is the ultimate requirement if we want to use class-inheritance as a design pattern. Is JavaScript really lacking this feature or just my understanding is vague? Does the new ES6 class-based structure brings this thing into picture?

Thanks for clarifying my concepts, I'm very confused over this as I've been doing things in Java in the past.

Comment: I don't quite get the question. In most OOP languages, when you instantiate a new instance of a class, the methods don't get copied to it, it is just that the class of the object is set, and when you call a method there is a mechanism to search for it in the associated class and its superclasses. That works the same way in javascript, it's just that you have a prototype instead of a class. ES6 classes are just syntactic sugar, it is equivalent of doing a `new Car(...)` in pure JS

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work - indeed your understanding seems to be too vague. In no serious OOP language every method is copied to every instance: In Java the compiler does some magic that lets you call `myCar.goBackward()`, while in JavaScript it's a completely transparent runtime construct that lets you do `myCar.goBackward()`. It doesn't affect  design at all - it's just more flexible

Comment: No, ES6 `class` does not bring a new structure, it only brings new syntax - the concept of how inheritance works hasn't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, a constructor function contains a `.prototype` property that contains any methods defined for that object (either with direct assignment to the prototype in ES5 or with the `class` keyword in ES6).

Then, when you instantiate a new object with that constructor, the object is given a pointer to the prototype.  When a method is called on that object, the Javascript interpreter will look first on the object itself for a property with that name and, if not found there, it will then go search the prototype chain.

So, the only thing that is "copied" to a newly created object in Javascript is a pointer to the prototype.  And, this works identically in ES5 and ES6.  The `class` syntax in ES6 is just new syntax for doing what we were manually doing already in ES5 (assigning methods to the prototype object).

In fact, you can even get the prototype if you want with `Object.getPrototypeOf()`.  It's important to realize that the new object contains a pointer to the prototype object (not a copy).  If subsequent changes are made to the prototype object, it is "live" and all instantiated objects before or after will see that change.

```
class Car {
    constructor(brand, model) {
        // initialize instance data
        this.brand = brand;
        this.model = model;
    }
    goForward() {
        console.log("goForward");
    }
    goBackward() {
        console.log("goBackward");
    }
}

let c = new Car("Toyota", "Corolla");
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(c));    // shows the two methods goForward, goBackward
console.log(c.brand);      // "Toyota"
```

> Now if Car class has goForward() or goBackward() methods, all of them will get copied to myCar object.

The new object is given a pointer to the prototype.  The methods are not copied individually.

> According to my understanding, this copying of data and methods is the ultimate requirement if we want to use class-inheritance as a design pattern.

This is just not true.  Inheritance does not require copying of all methods to the new object.  There are actually many different ways to achieve proper inheritance. Javascript uses a prototype.  C++ uses compile time binding.  I don't know the internals of Java myself, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367152/how-does-inheritance-in-java-work) refers to a method table that each object in Java is given a pointer to.

> Does the new ES6 class-based structure brings this thing into picture?

ES6 does not change how inheritance works internally in Javascript.  ES6 just introduces the `class` syntax which is a different way of declaring an object constructor and methods, but it results in the same internal structure as the way we manually declared methods on the prototype in ES5.