# Can anyone help me regarding mulitple inheritance in java?

Tags: java, oop, object, multiple-inheritance

```
  class A{} 
  class B extends A{}
```

here is it the case that B is extending A alongwith object class.

- We all know, in java, all classes by default inherits Object class.
- But it is also there that multiple inheritance is not allowed in java.
- Then when we inherit a class, what happens with this rule?

Comment: Inheriting from Object isn't multiple inheritance. It's single inheritance.

Comment: Because the class you're inheriting from inherits from `Object`.

Comment: Multiple inheritance means a single class extending multiple classes, not a class extending a class which in turn extends a class.

Comment: Cat inherits Mammal, which inherits Animal. One may say that Cat inherits Mammal and Cat also inherits Animal, which is true. Still, this is not multiple inheritance.

Comment: `ArrayList` extends `AbstractList` which extends `AbstractCollection` which extends `Object`. One single inheritance chain. Everything other than Object itself has one direct superclass.

Comment: @PRAJWALBHAGAT If you want to add code to your question, [edit] your question. Code in comments is really unclear.

Comment: @PRAJWALBHAGAT Each class extends a single class. See my previous comment.

Comment: You can use Java interfaces to have a sort of multiple inheritance. I find that I prefer this to having multiple inheritance with objects.

Comment: `B` extends `A`. `A` extends `Object`. That is a single inheritance chain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does inheritance in Java work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367152/how-does-inheritance-in-java-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We all know, in java, all classes by default inherits Object class.

Yes.  But I suspect that you don't understand what that really means.

What it means is that if a class is not declare (via an explicit `extend`) to inherit from some class, then it implicitly inherits from `Object`.

```
class A {}           // implicitly inherits Object

class B extends A {} // explicitly inherits A
```

To say this in other words:

- `A` has `Object` as its only *direct* superclass
- `B` has `A` as its only *direct* superclass.
- `B` has `Object` as an *indirect* superclass.

This is single inheritance.  Multiple inheritance would be if `B` had `A` *and* `Object` as *direct* superclasses.